# How can I add page to database after being modified by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am making a dynamic table that you can add rows to it and when the user presses the save button I want the whole HTML code at that moment to go into a database variable. What I tried so far was the `ob_start();`and I tried sending them through POST but I couldn't because I don't know how many rows and variables are there. This is my code so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
       var index = 1;
    function insertRow(){
                var table=document.getElementById("myTable");
                var row=table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
                var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
                var t1=document.createElement("input");
                    t1.id = "txtName"+index;
                    cell1.appendChild(t1);
                var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
                var t2=document.createElement("input");
                    t2.id = "txtAge"+index;
                    cell2.appendChild(t2);
                var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
                var t3=document.createElement("input");
                    t3.id = "txtGender"+index;
                    cell3.appendChild(t3);
                var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
                var t4=document.createElement("input");
                    t4.id = "txtOccupation"+index;
                    cell4.appendChild(t4);
          index++;

    }
    </script>
<table id="myTable">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Occupation and Employer</th>
        <th>Add</th>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtName" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtAge" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtGender" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtOccupation" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="btnAdd" class="button-add" onClick="insertRow()" value="add"></input></td>
        </tr>
</table>
<input type=button name='save' value='save'>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to save a record for each row of your tables? Do you want to save a record whenever insertRow is called?

Comment: I think it would be easier to just save the whole html of the new page than saving each time a row is added/deleted. It would save everytime you press on the save button

Comment: It is easier to save that way indeed, but it would not be wise, that would violate everything databases stand for and will cause you a lot of headaches on the long run. It is much better to store each row in a separate record and each cell as separate attributes. Then later you will be able to do some intelligent parsing.

Comment: but I don't know how many rows there are. it's a dynamic table and I need to show it to the user every time he opens the home.php page. I was thinking I would just echo the page but if I am going to do it separately I don't think I would be able to show it.

Comment: Why not? You can select the records and in a PHP foreach echo them out. Should not be too difficult.

Comment: alright I am gonna try it out thanks.